# R text mining n grams(bigrams) no result returned. Anyone has same experience?

Tags: r, text-mining, n-gram, tidytext

I'm using tidytext packages for n grams text mining.
I tried on 2 columns of texts, n grams (bigrams) function is working well for one but 0 obs returned for the other one. 2 columns from same resource so no diff with format but just diff content. Anyone knows why?

codes:
`result=unnest_tokens(table,bigrams,txt,token="ngrams",n=2)`

Comment: Please, add a reproducible example coming from your data.

Comment: Yep, we are going to need to see some example data to help you out here. Check out this question from some help on how to get started with a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Add an example with token data, like use Shakespeare which you can get online.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments. It's company data I can't post here. This codes applies well to other data tables.

I just find the issue. NA! NA! NA!. remember to remove NAs before process.

MW